# merge single table column with different types

Tags: c#, ms-access, ms-access-2007

**Table Columns**

1. **or_cv_no**

   - here is where 'cv_no' and 'or_no' stored
2. **type**

   - different types are 'CV' and 'OR'
3. **amount**

   - here is where 'cv_amt' and 'or_amt' stored
4. **date**

   - data that is being fetched has same date

**my query is this**

```
SELECT IIF(type = 'CV', or_cv_no) AS cv_no, IIF(type = 'CV', amount) AS cv_amt,  IIF(type = 'OR', or_cv_no) AS or_no, IIF(type = 'OR', amount) AS or_amt FROM transacAmt
```

**and the output is**

[image]

**how can i output it to look like this sample:**

```
| cv_no | cv_amt | or_no | or_amt |
|---------------------------------|
| 1234  | 1,500  | 4321  | 1,200  |
|-------+--------+-------+--------|
| 7777  | 1,700  | 2222  | 1,760  |
|-------+--------+-------+--------|
| 1111  | 1,900  | 3333  | 1,530  |
|-------+--------+-------+--------|
|       |        | 5355  | 1,420  |
|-------+--------+-------+--------|
|       |        | 1355  | 4,566  |
```

**EDIT: The output must be like this: marked 'x' must be removed.. or be filled by data**
[image]

Comment: What is the relation between cv and or? try using summation

Comment: How do you know that cv_no=1234 is supposed to be in the same row as or_no=4321?  what is the relationship here?  If there were some additional column that specified that relationship, i think the solution to this problem would become obvious.  I do see the problem you face.  I'm still thinking about how to solve this.  If you have any more context to lend me, I might arrive at an answer faster.  Thanks.

Comment: they all have same date..